# Connect to websocket server using IP address with Python websockets library

Tags: python, websocket, tcp

New to Python. I'm trying to connect to a websocket server using the actual IP address.

Connecting using the websocket URL works fine:

```
import websocket

def on_message(wsapp, message):
    print(message)

ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("wss://api.server.com:443/ws/stream", on_message=on_message)
ws.run_forever()
```

However, I extracted the server IP addresses using traceroute and the following doesn't work:

```
import websocket

def on_message(wsapp, message):
    print(message)

ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("wss://1.2.3.4:443/ws/stream", on_message=on_message)
ws.run_forever()
```

(not the actual domain or IP address)

Is there a way to connect using the IP address, rather than the URL?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to connect using the IP address, rather than the URL?

It depends on the server setup, but in most cases this will not work:

- If there are several domains with different configurations on the same IP address, then the domain name is essential to pick the right configuration. Such virtual server setups are very common today.
- Since you use `wss://` TLS is used which requires to validate the certificate of the server. Validation will fail if the name used in the URL (i.e. IP address instead of domain in your case) does not match what the certificate is for. It is possible but very uncommon to have an IP address in the certificate.